# Using a Spring Bean from another project - Entity Manager setup.

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependencies, autowired

I understand that the way these projects have been structured isn't necessarily good design, but i have found myself working on a project which has the following format and have a dependency and spring bean configuration issue:


Project A : 
Is a Spring Project. Spring configuration is in an XML file. The project consists of many different beans and classes. Some of these classes are Services which make calls to a database(JPA/Hibernate is used). So in the Spring configuration file there is an entityManagerFactory defined, a Datasource etc and all the beans needed to perform database operations.

Project B:
Is also a Spring project, and also contains various beans and classes. This project also contains classes which make calls to a database(using JPA/Hibernate). So the Spring configuration also defined an entityManagerFactory/datasource etc. The project contains a series of Entity Classes which are scanned by the entityManagerFactory using the property 'packagesToScan'. The configuration is using Java Config.

The problem:
A bean in Project A needs to use a bean from Project B. The bean from project B is a Service class which reads data from the database. I want to be able to inject the bean from Project B into the class from Project A. I am using gradle in both projects, so have added Project B into Project A as a gradle dependency. 
I tried adding a  to the configuration from Project A to scan the package in Project B which contains the Java Config. I thought this would enable me to autowire the class from Project B into Project A. However, i am getting an exception that the entities in Project A are not managed entities and that autowiring is failing. Does this mean i need to scan the entities in Project B with the entityManager in Project A? Does this mean i cannot autowire a bean which has already been configured in the configuration of another project? Do i need to add this bean to Project A xml configuration and do all the property setting there, copied from Project B?